# Manually sort Commerce 2 products within the taxonomy term (category)

Tags: views, 8, commerce

I have a view to display my products (categorized by taxonomy term) in the frontend.

I have another view admin/commerce/products to add new products in the backend.

How do I implement and configure [DraggableViews](https://www.drupal.org/project/draggableviews) so I am able to manually sort my products within the taxonomy term category?

**Update**

My steps what I tried:

- Created a new view (for sorting the products)
- added the title field
- add the field `Draggableviews: Product`
- In the sort criteria add `Draggableviews: DraggableViews Weight (asc)`

**1)** The problem here is that I get some double values?

I have another (taxonomy) view to display my products (categorised by taxonomy term).

**2)** In this view I am not able to add the sort criteria add `Draggableviews: DraggableViews Weight (asc)`? Draggableviews is not available in this view?

Comment: Following the [Draggable Views documentation](https://www.drupal.org/node/283498) might be useful.

Comment: @Kojo I did already.

Comment: If I'm not wrong you need to create one Views with TWO displays (or two Views with one display each). One display visualizes the items to the users, and the other display is the admin display to sort them. In your question I only see one View with one display.

Comment: @sanzante but I think Draggable Views in combination with Search API is not possible. Or is there a solution for this?

Comment: Probably they are not compatible because Search API already sorts the results, I guess. Usually you can't sort manually the results of a search.